# How do I export an object with added prototype methods in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have an object in a file and want to be able to require that file and then create new instances of the object at whim, but I've hit a snag. This seems so incredibly basic, what am I missing.

**hat.js**

```
function Hat(owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
Hat.prototype.tip = function() {
    console.log("and he (" + owner + ") tipped his hat, just like this");
}
exports.Hat = Hat;
```

**node terminal**

*Attempt 1*

```
> require('./hat.js');
> var mighty_duck = new Hat('Emilio');
  ReferenceError: Hat is not defined
```

*Attempt 2*

```
> var Hat = require('./hat.js');
> var mighty_duck = new Hat('Emilio');
  { owner: 'Emilio' }
> mighty_duck.tip();
  TypeError: Object #<Hat> has no method 'tip'
```

## Edit

I, most unfortunately, left out what turned out to be the biggest problem bit. The fact that I was trying to use

```
util.inherits(Hat, EventEmitter);
```

So my hat.js would actually be

```
function Hat(owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
Hat.prototype.tip = function() {
    console.log("and he (" + owner + ") tipped his hat, just like this");
}
util.inherits(Hat, EventEmitter);
exports.Hat = Hat;
```

This is an issue, because, *apparently* it is important to have your `inherits` call *before* you start extending the prototype. The fix is simple, move the `inherits` call up a few lines

```
function Hat(owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
util.inherits(Hat, EventEmitter);
Hat.prototype.tip = function() {
    console.log("and he (" + owner + ") tipped his hat, just like this");
}
exports.Hat = Hat;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing your require wrong:

```
var Hat = require('./hat.js').Hat;
```

Is what you want. When you do `exports.Hat = Hat;` you are exporting an object (`exports`) with a propery of `Hat`. So when you require `'./hat.js'` you get the object, and need to access the `Hat` property.

From node repl:

```
> require('./hat.js');
{ Hat: [Function: Hat] }
> require('./hat.js').Hat;
[Function: Hat]
> var Hat = require('./hat.js').Hat;
undefined
> var mighty_duck = new Hat('Emilio');
undefined
> mighty_duck.tip();
and he (Emilio) tipped his hat, just like this
```

Of course that was causing an error since you said `owner` and not `this.owner` in `tip()`, but after I changed that it worked fine :)

If you want to just do

```
var Hat = require('./hat.js'),
    hat = new Hat('Emilio');
```

Then change your export to:

```
module.exports = exports = Hat;
```

And it works:

```
> require('./hat.js');
[Function: Hat]
> var Hat = require('./hat.js');
undefined
> var hat = new Hat('Emilio');
undefined
> hat.tip();
and he (Emilio) tipped his hat, just like this
```

**EDIT** Cleaned up and inherits from EventEmitter:

```
var util = require('util'),
    events = require('events');

var Hat = exports.Hat = function(owner) {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.owner = owner;
}

util.inherits(Hat, events.EventEmitter);

Hat.prototype.tip = function() {
    console.log("and he (" + this.owner + ") tipped his hat, just like this");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly correctly. Unfortunately for me, I left out the problem bit (that I just discovered) in my example code. I was trying to extend EventEmitter.

Comment: extending EventEmitter doesn't change how you export; I added some cleaned up code that inherits from event emitter.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your are correct that extending it doesn't change how you export, but it does kill your prototype if you don't call the `inherits` **first**. An odd quirk. Cheers!

Comment: Right it inherits via `Hat.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;` or something similar which will **set** your prototype, overwriting anything that is there.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look here: http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/

you might try this instead:

```
function Hat(owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
Hat.prototype.tip = function() {
    console.log("and he (" + this.owner + ") tipped his hat, just like this");
}
module.exports = Hat;
```

and then sth. like this:

```
var hat = require('./hat.js');
var mighty_duck = new hat('Emilio');
mighty_duck.tip()
```

Comment: setting exports does not work, try doing this and requiring the file in the repl. You get an empty object. If you want to overwrite the object in `exports` you need to do `module.exports = exports = ...`.

Comment: @Chad Yes, you're right. I've corrected my answer, so it works now. Thanks!