# how export JS module in node

Tags: javascript, module, export

I'm trying to import a string.prototype.method in a test file.

MODULE FILE:

```js
module.exports = String.prototype.camelCase = function camelCase() {
  let string = "";
  this.split(" ")
    .map((el, i) => {
      i == 0
        ? (string += el.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toLowerCase()))
        : (string += el.replace(/\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase()));
    })
    .join("");
  return string;
};
```

TEST FILE:

```js
const test = require("ava");
import { camelCase } from "./index.js";

test("test", (t) => {
  t.pass("hello world".camelCase(), "HelloWorld");
});
```

when I trun npm test that's what ava return:

```sh
> js-util-library@1.0.0 test
> ava


  ✖ No tests found in test.mjs

  ─

  Uncaught exception in test.mjs

  file:///home/xlrnz/Documenti/dev/js-util-library/test.mjs:2
  import { camelCase } from "./index.js";
           ^^^^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Named export 'camelCase' not found. The requested module './index.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
```

I don't understand, maybe some problem with string.prototype methods on export?

Thanks to @vitaliykotov I've learned something that previously I don't know.

Everything beautiful but now when I try npm test with this file:

```js
const test = require('ava')
```

that's the result:

```sh
> js-util-library@1.0.0 test
> ava test.js


  ✖ No tests found in test.js

  ─

  Uncaught exception in test.js

  ReferenceError: require is not defined

  › file://test.js:1:14
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the error your module(and all modules in Node by default) is CommonJS module. So to import something from it you should use **require()** function.
Also [it's possible](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html) to tell Node to treat modules as **ECMAScript**, but then all modules should be defined this way

Comment: Thanks, so if I've undertand I need to use require('./index.js') and any function inside of this file get imported?

Comment: Using require should eliminate the error. But it seems to me that to make everything work properly, you also have to rewrite your module a bit. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13364736/11900833) how to export objects

Comment: thanks man! check out the edit if you can. now when i run npm test from terminal node tell me that require is not defined!

Comment: hard to say without seeing all setup files, but usually this error occurs when you run your JS code in browser/client side environment